# Repeat a formula in Excel that subtracts the amount just calculated

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to calculate a percentage of a number minus 150 and repeat that five times.

For instance:

- Total price = `4541.39`
- Column B2 = 5 chairs
- Column C2 = price of 5 chairs
- Tax = 14.5% each
- Shipping = 150 each

I need to take the total price, subtract 14.5%, subtract 150.00, then take that total, subtract 14.5%, then subtract 150.00 and continue this 5 times.

The answer is `1513.21` but I can't get this in excel. Thanks

Comment: Algebra to the rescue

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is easy to find the desired price for this one instance (which is 5 chairs) but I guess you are looking for a solution that works for `x` amount of products using the same logic. If that's the case I guess you may want to add `vba` to your tags as `vba` may be able to automate the process while formula based solution can't.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 ways, they are based on the following:
1. x1 = TotalPrice*(1-tax)-150
2. x2 = x2*(1-tax)-150
..
5. x5 = x4*(1-tax)-150

Let's say that the total amount is in cell B1, tax in B2 and shipping in b3.

You can use the formula:

```
=(((((((((B1*(1-$B$2))-$B$3)*(1-$B$2))-$B$3)*(1-$B$2))-$B$3)*(1-$B$2))-$B$3)*(1-$B$2))-$B$3
```

or using a little algebra:

```
=((1-B2)^5)*B1-B3*((1-B2)^4) -B3*((1-B2)^3)-B3*((1-B2)^2)-B3*(1-B2)-B3
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Building on the excellent work of @CTE6, you could express this as an array-type formula as follows:

```
=C2*F2^B2-E2*SUMPRODUCT(F2^(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,B2))-1))
```

which means that you can vary the number of chairs by changing the value in B2.

[image]

The multiplier F2 is given by

```
=(100-D2)/100
```

Comment: This is incredible!! Just one quick advice you may want to lock `A1` and `A:A` in your `ROW` function so it will not shift if the user drags the formula down for instance. I never know you can use INDEXT within ROW like that, and never know you can use SUMPRODUCT to calculate algebra in this fashion!! Great answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, the mathematical formula that represents your problem is:

```
((1.145 * x) + 150) * 5 = 4,541.39
```

So how do you reverse this?

```
Step 01  (1.145 * x) + 150 = 4,541.39 / 5
Step 02  (1.145 * x) = (4541.39 / 5) - 150
Step 03  x = ((4541.39 / 5 ) - 150) / 1.145
```

So what is the Excel formula?

```
     A         B         C         D         E
1    Total     Quantity  Shipping  Tax       Unit Price
2    4541.39   5         150       0.145     = ((A2 / B2) - C2) / (1 + D2)
```

Another problem, my answer is 662.2515284!!

Which is of course not your answer.

So maybe I've misunderstood your problem?